# Reusable Component on Same Screen Overwrites previous component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a component that I want to reuse in the same screen.

The reusable component makes a fetch call based on passed in params, stores the results in local state, and displays the results.

ScreenPage.js

```
<View>
  <ReusableComponent id={1} apiCall={call1} >
  <ReusableComponent id={2} apiCall={call2}>
  <ReusableComponent id={3} apiCall={call3}>
</View>
```

It seems like the last passed in component's params overwrite all of the previous component params before the fetch happens. So the id and apiCall for all 3 components becomes 3 and call3.

How do I keep this from happening?

ReusableComponent.js

```
ReusableComponent = ({id, apiCall}) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  _getUserData = () => {
    fetch('url', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          action: apiCall,
          id: id
        })
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          setIsLoading(false)
          setUsers(data.response)
          _playersRunsByIndex()
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err))

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    _getUserData()
  }, [id])

...

return (
  <FlatList
    data={users}
    ...
  />
)
```

Comment: share `ReusableComponent` code.

Comment: @JuniusL. - added

Comment: add unique `key` properties